# SwiftUI can you have a view in a loop?

Tags: swiftui, view, navigationview

In the app I am developing, I have multiple (23) screens that are the almost the same.  They differ by a picture.  The data for all of these can be kept in an array [String].  I tried calling a NavigationView (separate screen) inside a for loop but couldn't get it to work.  Should this be possible?   Is there any examples out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and pass through 2 things between the views.

> `count` too keep a track of each view and a `array` to keep a track of each of the information inside of the view.

Here would be a somewhat example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView1: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    @State private var info = ["a", "b", "c"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 1")
            Text("Content: a")
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2(count: count + 1, info: info)) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    var count: Int
    var info: [String]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(count)
            Text(info: info[count]
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3(count: count + 1, info: info)) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    var count: Int
    var info: [String]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(count)
            Text(info: info[count]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in this approach there is a list of navigational links all based on a central View.   I've seen this before.   I was wondering if there was a way to have a list of Views daisy-chained.   Example: View1 will have "a" and a next navigational link to View2 which will have "b" and have a navigational link to View3 which will have "c", and so on.    I'm not sure if that is possible

Comment: I see. Here is something that if you definitely knew how many elements that would be in the array. Just pass through a count and the array between each view. I'm not a 100% sure how to do this.